# how prevent duplicate code in wicket

Tags: wicket, dry

Sorry my english is bad

I have two class profile and EditProfile

in both class i have

```
protected void addContent(PageParameters pageParameters) {
        final String email = pageParameters.get(ListUser.USER_EMAIL).toString();
        final User loggedUser = getLoggedUser();

        if (email == null) {
            redirectToInterceptPage(new ErrorPage404(null));
            return;
        }

        User userByEmail = userService.findByEmail(email);

        if (userByEmail == null) {
            redirectToInterceptPage(new ForbiddenPage403(null));
            return;
        }

        final UserDetachableModel user = new UserDetachableModel(userByEmail);

        // If the user is not active, there is no need to edit your profile.
        if (!user.getObject().isActive()) {
            redirectToInterceptPage(new ErrorPage404(null));
            return;
        }

        // Only admins can see the profile of other users.
        if (!loggedUser.getUserRole().equals(UserRole.ADMIN) && !loggedUser.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(email)) {
            redirectToInterceptPage(new ForbiddenPage403(null));
            return;
        }

    ......PROCESS TO SEE PROFILE OR EDIT PROFILE........
}
```

I use a CustomMountedPage that i use to hide the serial number of wicket.
Example http://HOST/Page/subPage?**ID**&**PARAMS** to see  http://HOST/Page/subPage?**PARAMS** and access to another profile

How prevent duplicate code!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Panels. They have their own markup file like a normal page but you can use them in any other Wicket-Page as a component.

Have a look at [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/panel.html) to see how to use panels correctly.

Comment: I have to not block an entire page or part of it, just make an action in a given condition.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you... can you rephrase the your question?